# Where do timers live in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib timer objects to register my own update function for an animation.  I can't seem to stop the callbacks once they start though without keeping a reference to the timer object.

It has been my experience thus far that when I create an object in matplotlib I am given a reference to it but it is also added to a list inside some other object (axis in figures, lines in axis etc.) which can then be queried later.  I cannot find where timer objects live however.  My problem can be summarized by this code snippet

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def update():
    plt.get_current_fig_manager().canvas.figure.patch.set_facecolor(str(np.random.random()))
    plt.draw()

def start_animation():
    timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval = 50)
    timer.add_callback(update)
    timer.start()

fig = plt.figure()
start_animation()
```

Run the above code snippet, then try to programmatically stop the flashing.  The function that needs to get called is

```
timer.remove_callback(update).
```

To be clear.  I know that I can just keep a reference to a timer object and this problem goes away.  I am looking for an explanation of where this object must be living in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how bout

```
 self.timer =  fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=100)
 ...
 self.timer.remove_callback(...)
```

to clarify the reference is in a callafter method.
there is no reference stored in your figure or your canvas
you can see this in the backend source

```
def new_timer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates a new backend-specific subclass of :class:`backend_bases.Timer`.
    This is useful for getting periodic events through the backend's native
    event loop. Implemented only for backends with GUIs.

    optional arguments:

    *interval*
      Timer interval in milliseconds
    *callbacks*
      Sequence of (func, args, kwargs) where func(*args, **kwargs) will
      be executed by the timer every *interval*.
    """
    return TimerTk(self._tkcanvas, *args, **kwargs)
```

which simply returns a TimerTK instance.  the reference continues to live because the in the `TimerTk.start()` method you see a callafter that continues to keep the timer from garbage collecting

```
 class TimerTK(TimerBase):
       ...
       def _timer_start(self):
           self._timer_stop()
           self._timer = self.parent.after(self._interval, self._on_timer)
```

and that is why every example shows saving your own reference to the timer

Comment: I understand that it is not hard to keep a reference to the object myself.  I am looking for a better understanding of matplotlib more than a quick fix.  I know the reference is hidden somewhere because it keeps getting called but I couldn't find it any place I looked

Comment: there I elaborated slightly